# What is the value for BillingFlowParams.setDeveloperId

Tags: android, billing

The android billing documentaiton describes the BillingFlowParams method [setDeveloperId](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setdeveloperid), as next:

> Specify an optional obfuscated string of developer profile name. If
>   you pass this value, Google Play can use it for payment risk
>   evaluation. Do not use the account ID or the user's Google ID for this
>   field.

So what is exactly the vale to pass, and where to obtain it? Is it the licence key located in Development Tools \ Services & APIs?

It gets confusing when it says "developer profile name", which then would mean that this isn't the app specific license key.